# Almond.js and define() method. Throws: Uncaught Error: incorrect module build, no module name

Tags: requirejs, plotly, amd, js-amd, almond

- **The story is:**

In our firm we're slowly trying to adjust our huge application to use dynamic AMD module loader. We can't do it all at once, this is why we do it in steps: firstly we wish to rewrite all javascript into typescript using AMD requires and 'fake' modularity using [almond.js](https://github.com/requirejs/almond). After we rewrite everything, we'll switch to real dynamic module loader.

- **Here comes the problem**

When we include almond on the page, following error is thrown:

```
almond.js:414 Uncaught Error: See almond README: incorrect module build, no module name
    at define (almond.js:414)
    at plotly.js:7
    at plotly.js:7
```

It comes from several libraries, not just plotly. I managed to track it down, and it turns out that almond introduces `define()` which takes 3 required parameters, while plotly (and some other libraries) calls define() using one or two of them:

**Plotly:**

```
if (typeof define==="function" && define.amd ) {
  define([],f)
}
```

**Almond:**

```
define = function (name, deps, callback) {
    if (typeof name !== 'string') {
        throw new Error('See almond README: incorrect module build, no module name');
    }
    (...)
```

- **Question:**

Do you have any idea how to approach to solve this problem? We can load almond.js after Plotly.js, but we'd like to find better solution and use Plotly in conjuction with almond. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Almond's README states:

> Only useful for **built/bundled** AMD modules, does not do dynamic loading.

Emphasis added. The form of `define` without a string giving the module name as the first argument is used in files that have not been through a building or bundling process. An AMD bundler will take the `define` call and add the module name as the first parameter when it does the bundling. The files you refer to have not been included in a bundle, so they lack the module name.

Solution: use an AMD bundler, like [`r.js`](https://github.com/requirejs/r.js) to bundle your modules into a single bundle that Almond will use.